# Properly invoking an interactive script from elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an external command line program that I would like to invoke from elisp. This is easy enough with shell-command, but it doesn't work correctly when the command line program is interactive, which in my particular case it is: The invoked script sees EOF when it reads stdin when I call it like this:

```
  ;; upload command is a string with the name of
  ;; a python script and some args
  (shell-command upload-command
                 (get-buffer-create "*upload output*")))))
```

The python script identified by upload-command may ask some yes/no questions and it may prompt for a password, for which I'd like masked input. Ideally, all of this interaction would occur within the minibuffer.

How can I arrange things so that my external interactive command interacts with the user via minibuffer when called via elisp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use either `make-comint` or `make-comint-in-buffer`:

```
(make-comint-in-buffer "upload-script-process" "*upload output*" upload-command)
```

This will runs the script in a buffer like a `shell` buffer, so it doesn't fulfill the requirement of having all interaction happen in the minibuffer.  It *will*, however, automatically read passwords in masked form from the minibuffer, provided the password prompt matches `comint-password-prompt-regexp`.

Note that `upload-command` in this example here needs to be the name of an executable file on `exec-path`.  Any extra switches or other arguments to the script have to be passed as string arguments to `make-comint`:

```
(make-comint-in-buffer "upload-script-process" "*upload output*" 
   upload-command nil "--verbose" "--other-option")
```

See the Emacs documentation for more details.